# Python choose method based on argparse

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I want to execute different methods based on arguments from CLI. My `main.py`:

```
from option import Option
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument( "--word", "-w", help="Find score for word", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

option = Option()
option.score_from_word(args.word)
```

and `Option.py`:

```
class Option():
    SCRABBLES_SCORES = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
                (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]
    global LETTER_SCORES 
    LETTER_SCORES = {letter: score for score, letters in SCRABBLES_SCORES
             for letter in letters.split()}

    def score_from_word(self,word):
        score = 0
        for w in word:
            if w in LETTER_SCORES.keys():
                score += LETTER_SCORES.get(w)
        print(score)

    def score_from_file(self):
        file = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('dictionary.txt', "r")]
        print(max(sum(LETTER_SCORES[c.upper()] for c in word) for word in file))
```

If in command line I write: python -w KOT it return 7 and it's ok. But how to add another argument and depends on him choose other method to execute?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you mean by this?  "But how to add another argument and depends on choosing other method to execute?"

Comment: Let's say, in command line I write python main.py -w KOT and method score_from_word executes. But if I write python main.py -f, method score_from_file will execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another argument, and find in which case you are by testing on the args (`Namespace`) attributes.

```
from option import Option
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument( "--word", "-w", help="Find score for word", type=str)
group.add_argument( "--file", "-f", help="Find score for words in file", action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

option = Option()
if args.word:
    option.score_from_word(args.word)
elif args.file:
    option.score_from_file()
```

Comment: May want to consider making these options mutually exclusive with [`ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion)

Comment: @mistiru I didnt expect it could be so easy... But after -f I dont want any other arguments. Like python main.py -f has to return the highest score from file